# Dynamically creating static variables in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js

How does one go about dynamically creating a function in javascript, but have a variable be "dynamically hardcoded" (?).  Preferably without using *eval()*.

I thought this would be the cleanest way to pass async.parallel() a few parameters in nodejs without having to bind objects.

```
function makeFunction( param1){

  return function(){
      alert(param1); 
  }

}
```

Actual Output from *console.log( makeFunction("Hello World") );*

`return function(){
    alert(param1); 
}`

Desired Output from *console.log( makeFunction("Hello World") );*

`return function(){
    alert("Hello World"); 
}`

Comment: Why do you want to hard code it? It will anyways hold on to 'Hello World' because of clojure. If you call it again with "Bye World", it will still return as attached to param1, but param1 there, because of clojure, will have 'Bye World'

Comment: Only because you don't see the closure scope in the output, `param1 === "Hello World"`. There is no need to create a function that contains the string literal in its source code, it even would be less performant than the closure.

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeFunction(param1){
  return new Function('alert(\'' + param1 + '\');')
}

console.log(makeFunction('helloWorld').toString())
```

only like that. `new Function` is a little bit "evaly" but in fact it's much better (or less evil).

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel it'd be better than using `eval`, but probably this would be what you want:

```
function makeFunction(param1) {
    var F=function () {
        alert(param1);
    };

    var text=['"', '"'].join(param1);
    text=String.prototype.replace.call(F, 'param1', text);
    text=['return ', ';'].join(text);
    return (new Function(text))();
}
```